# Specified cast is not valid.(integer value in datatable)

Tags: c#, asp.net, casting, datatable, null

I want to check  the following field in the datatable against null  :

```
r.Field<int>("prod_type")

if (r.Field<int>("prod_type") != null && 
    !string.IsNullOrEmpty(r.Field<int>("prod_type").ToString()))
```

but I get the following exception :

> Specified cast is not valid.

How to check the integer value in the datatable against null or empty ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`Field`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360891.aspx) extension method supports nullable types. Use [`HasValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sksw8094.aspx) to check if a nullable is not null:

```
if (r.Field<int?>("prod_type").HasValue)
```

Comment: thanks a lot .can i use this method with any type like `byte[]` for example :

`r.Field<byte[]?>("doc_signed").HasValue` ?

Comment: @just_name: Yes, with any [value type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx). Reference tyes like string are nullable types by default.

Comment: hmmm i can't find the `HasValue`

Comment: `r.Field<byte[]?>("doc_signed").HasValue` is this syntaxly right ?

Comment: @just_name: Sorry, i have overlooked the array, any array is a reference type even if the containing type is a value type. So you could have a nullable-byte with `r.Field<byte?>("doc_signed")` but not the array. This is a reference type and can be null by default: `if(r.Field<byte[]>("prod_type")!= null)`.

Answer (score 2):

The error you are getting is indicating that the field in the datatable is **not of type `int`**. If it is of type `int` it can't hold null value, instead you can try `int?` which is [Nullable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx).

```
r.Field<int?>("prod_type") != null
```

Comment: @just_name, then it is `int?`, Nullable int

Answer (score 1):

If `prod_type` is indeed an `int` field in the database, try doing  it like this:

```
if (r.Field<int?>("prod_type") != null)
```